# Update command in c#

Tags: sql, sql-server, c#-3.0

This is a simple update code. But this code does not update my table.

```
static string db = (System.Web.Configuration.WebConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["strcon"].ConnectionString);

SqlConnection connect = new SqlConnection(db);
connect.Open();

string Command = "Update Order Set Name = @Name, Apple_gmail_id = @Apple_gmail_id, Apple_gmail_Pass = @Apple_gmail_Pass, Mobilenumber  = @Mobilenumber, VillageName = @VillageName, VillageDegree = @VillageDegree, CountOfGem = @CountOfGem, Amount = @Amount WHERE Order_ID = @Order_ID";

SqlCommand cmdIns = new SqlCommand(Command, connect);

cmdIns.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Name", GetDataValue(TextBox1.Text));
cmdIns.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Apple_gmail_id", GetDataValue(TextBox2.Text));
cmdIns.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Apple_gmail_Pass", GetDataValue(TextBox3.Text));
cmdIns.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Mobilenumber", GetDataValue(TextBox4.Text));
cmdIns.Parameters.AddWithValue("@VillageName", GetDataValue(TextBox5.Text));
cmdIns.Parameters.AddWithValue("@VillageDegree", GetDataValue(TextBox6.Text));
cmdIns.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CountOfGem", radio);
cmdIns.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Amount", GetDataValue(txtmab.Text));

cmdIns.ExecuteNonQuery();
connect.Close();
```

and it is my code to connect to database in `web.config`:

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="strcon" 
         connectionString="Server=.;Database=Gem;Integrated Security=True;" />
</connectionStrings>
```

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to add a parameter for `@Order_ID` specified in the `WHERE` clause.